# Using 2-port LSI 9286-8e card to control 24 SAS HDDs

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, storage, sas, raid6

I would like to rely on a RAID-on-chip solution to control 24 SAS hard drives in a direct-attached environment.  How would you approach this to get best bandwidth given that I'd like to spend less than $10,000 on the interconnect.

[I've read](http://www.servethehome.com/lsi-sas-9207-8e-sas-ii-sata-iii-hba-benchmarks/) that LSI 2208 chip can easily handle 8-drive SSD RAID6 in hardware.  I'd like to harness its power to control 24 SAS hard drives over an expander in an external enclosure.

Currently I use an Infortrend S24S-G2240 external enclosure.  It provides its own controller and expander.  I'd like to use LSI 2208 controller for RAID6 somehow instead of the mystery controller in the enclosure.

P.S.  I tried to create SAS-expander as a tag, but my rep on this site is low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're missing the obvious information... What type of external enclosure do you have, and what are its available connections?

Typically, external SAS controllers use 4-lane SAS SFF-8088 connectors to interface with the host-based adapter in the server.

[image]

Given that, the enclosure *should* have a SAS expander embedded on its backplane. That's how you'd be able to address the number of disks inside of the enclosure. Pretty standard.

I use [HP D2700 enclosures](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13404_na/13404_na.html), for instance. They have 25 x 2.5" disk bays and feature *two* chassis controllers that each take an SFF-8088 connection to the host system. I control them with either 1-port or 2-port LSI controllers. The expander is built into the external drive enclosure.

--Edit

Looking at the rear of the device you have, try connecting one port from your LSI HBA to P1 of the enclosure. Start there. I don't know if this device has multipath/MPIO capabilities, so you may need to contact support for that. But otherwise, this looks like any standard external JBOD unit... although, reading the specifications, it may be a SAS-attached SAN unit. You're better off using its embedded controller and logic rather than going the LSI approach.

[image]

Comment: Would something like this work? http://www.infortrend.com/us/products/models/ESDS%20S16S-J2000-S

Comment: You need a simple JBOD... HP, Supermicro and a few others make them.

Comment: [HP D2700 enclosure](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13404_na/13404_na.html)